# auto-py-to-exe/pyinstaller base_library error

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

I just finished a project and I need to convert it to a executable file.I'm using auto-py-to-exe which adds a nice UI to pyinstaller so it makes my work easier. The problem is that my scripts are using txt files located in the same directory(ex:`os.path.join(sys.path[0],"file.txt")`) and just adding by `--add-data C:/path/to/file.txt;`. doesn't seem to work as I get a "Unhandled exception in script" error. This is the full error message:

```
  File "GUI.py", line 141, in <module>
    frame = MyFrame()
  File "GUI.py", line 40, in __init__
    with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0],"file.txt")) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\path\to\\\base_library.zip\\file.txt'
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?(I had to comment it as code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution so I'm posting it for anyone looking for it:seems like the current directory becomes \current directory\base_library.zip so sys.path[0] will return that instead of the directory the executable resides(something similar for the standalone --onefile .exe,same solution).The solution is simply to replace sys.path[0] with sys.path[0]).replace('\base_library.zip',''),which will allow the script to acces the current directory again.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this problem is the line below:

```
os.chdir(sys.path[0])
```

Or maybe `sys.path[0]...`

I removed it, and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but solved it by changing:

```
os.path.join(sys.path[0],"file.txt")
```

with

```
os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"file.txt")
```